# Sistema de permissão de inscrição por limite

Tags: php, mysql, comparação, contador

No meu sistema de cursos, o formador tem que estipular a quantidade de alunos que podem se inscrever em cada turma e o aluno só vai poder se inscrever se o número de alunos inscritos for menor que o número estipulado pelo formador.

Pra isso eu resolvi colocar a comparação no formulário de inscrição do aluno na turma, porém, assim que o aluno entra na página a comparação não é feita e já aparece o aviso de "essa turma já está lotada".

Formulário de inscrição do aluno:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1 style="
                margin-top:100px;">Inscrição</h1>
            <p> </p>
            <p class="lead"></p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <form id="cadastro" method="post" action="banco/updateP.php" style="
                    text-align: left;
                    margin-top:50px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="FORMACAO">Formação: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="FORMACAO" name="FORMACAO" value="<?php echo $formacao; ?>">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="TURMA">Turma: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="TURMA" name="TURMA" value="<?php echo $turma; ?>">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="COLABORADOR">Colaborador: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="COLABORADOR" name="COLABORADOR">
                                <option>Selecione...</option>
                                <?php while($colab = mysqli_fetch_array($queryColaboradores)) { ?> 
                                <option value="<?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?>"><?php echo $colab['NOME']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="AREA">Área: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="AREA" name="AREA">
                                <option> MITV </option>
                                <option> CTCA </option>
                                <option> VSPA </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="DATA">Data: </label>
                            <select  class="form-control" id="DATA" name="MES">
                                <option> jan </option>
                                <option> fev </option>
                                <option> mar </option>
                                <option> abr </option>
                                <option> mai </option>
                                <option> jun </option>
                                <option> jul </option>
                                <option> ago </option>
                                <option> set </option>
                                <option> out </option>
                                <option> nov </option>
                                <option> dez </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-group" method="post" style="
                    text-align: left;">
                            <label  for="PREVISTO">Status: </label>
                            <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="PREVISTO" name="PREVISTO" value="Previsto">
                         </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"> Salvar </i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                            <strong>Hey! </strong> Antes de realizar o cadastro, certifique-se de que não se esqueceu de nada! :)
                        </div>
                        <?php 
                            //Teste de contador
                            $limite = "SELECT * FROM turmas WHERE ID = 'TURMA' and NOME = 'FORMACAO'";

                            $contador = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS ComparaLIMITE FROM participantes WHERE TURMA = 'turma' and FORMACAO = 'formacao'";
                            if ($contador <= $limite) { 
                                header("Location: inscricao.php"); 
                                } 
                            else { 
                                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                        alert("Essa turma estava completa");
                                        window.history.go(-1);
                                    </script>';
                                }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essa é a tabela do banco de dados que salva as turmas:

> ID, NOME,   FORMADOR,   OBJETIVO,   SALA,   DATA,   HORARIO,    LOCAL,  LIMITE

Essa é a tabela do banco de dados que salva as inscrições:

> ID, FORMACAO,   TURMA,  COLABORADOR,    AREA,   MES,    ANO,    PREVISTO    REALIZADO

Além disso, os componentes tipo rodapé da página, coisas que aparecem depois do meu php que tem o contador simplesmente desapareceram da página.

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse contador?

Comment: Adicione um `select` antes de fazer a inserção de dados. Ex: `SELECT limit FROM table WHERE id = ID-DA-TURMA;` e no `php` você adiciona uma condição. Ex: `if ($row->limit >= 5) { /* avisa para o usuário que não há vagas */ } else { /* Cria matricula */ }`

Comment: Mas por que 5 se o limite é o que eu vou pegar do cadastro?

Comment: O 5 é um exemplo. Utilize LEFT JOIN para retornar os dados das duas tabelas. A quantidade total e a quantidade de alunos cadastrados.

Answer (score 0):

Assim ficou a parte responsável pela comparação:

```
                             <?php 
                                    $sqlLimite = 'SELECT LIMITE FROM turmas WHERE ID = ' . $turma . ' and NOME = "' . $formacao . '"';
                                    //para retornar resultado
                                    $resultLimite = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlLimite);
                                    //para trazer resultados no formato array
                                    $limite = mysqli_fetch_array($resultLimite);

                                    //seleciona todos os registros quando turma = $turma e formacao = $formacao
                                    $sqlcontador = 'SELECT * FROM participantes WHERE TURMA = ' . $turma . ' and FORMACAO = "' . $formacao . '"';
                                    //para retornar o resultado
                                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlcontador);
                                    //contar quantos registros foram retornados
                                    $contador = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                                    if ($contador < $limite['LIMITE']) { 
                                        header("Location: inscricao.php"); 
                                        } 
                                    else { 
                                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                                                alert("Essa turma está completa");
                                                window.history.go(-1);
                                            </script>';
                                        }
                              ?>
```